Weak equivalences in model categories
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be any model category, if the composition $X\xrightarrow{f}Y\xrightarrow{g}Z$ is a weak equivalence in $\mathcal{C}$ and there is a pair of weak equivalences (automorphisms) $Y\xrightarrow{\alpha}Y\xrightarrow{\beta}Y$ such that $\alpha\circ\beta=\beta\circ\alpha=\mathsf{id}_{Y}$, then are the new compositions
$$X\xrightarrow{f}Y\xrightarrow{\alpha}Y\xrightarrow{g}Z\quad\text{ and }\quad X\xrightarrow{f}Y\xrightarrow{\beta}Y\xrightarrow{g}Z$$
still weak euivalences in $\mathcal{C}$?

Every (bicomplete) category admits a trivial model structure, in which the weak equivalences are precisely the isomorphisms and every morphism is both a fibration and a cofibration. You can find plenty of counter-examples in such categories.

Thanks for your answer! However the real question I would like to know is, is the conclusion I described upside established for any model categories?

@Frank I think this is atypical behavior. If $f\colon X\rightarrow Y$ is a weak equivalence and $g\colon X\rightarrow Y$ is any morphism, then factoring $f$ as $X\rightarrow Y\times Y\rightarrow Y$, where the first map is $(f,g)$ and the second is projection onto the first factor, and using the flip automorphism of $Y\times Y$, the condition implies that $g$, too, is weak equivalence. In other words, any morphism between weakly equivalent objects is a weak equivalence, or in yet other words the homotopy category is an EI-category.

That said, there are also examples where the property holds, e.g. any model category in which all morphisms are weak equivalences (such model structures correspond precisely to weak factorization systems).
